# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS headphone and microphone not working at the same time

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, headphones

In my desktop my headphone is connected with wire with following devices.
[image]
[image]

My problem is during a meeting when I select input device as `Microphone - Built-in Audio` I can not hear any sound but people from other end can hear me. When I switch input device to `Headset Microphone - Built-in Audio` I can hear but other people can not hear me. In both case output device is selected as `Headphones - Built-in Audio`.
How do I solve this problem?

N.B I don't know why images are not shown even though I added them. So here are the output device options

- HDMI - Built-in Audio
- Speakers - Built-in Audio
- Headphones - Built-in Audio

And here are input devices

- Headset Microphone - Built-in Audio
- Microphone - Built-in Audio

Hardware specs for audio for command `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`

```
    DeviceName: Intel HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: 91100000-911fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
--
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Dell Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 137
    Memory at 91230000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 91000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: How are your headphones and microphone connected? Do your headphones and microphone use the same cable or are they split with each going to a different audio port?

Comment: @MaximilianBallard yes same cable is used. my desktop also has single port input